# A scene in Friends where Joey remembers not understanding something

Tags: identify-this-episode, friends

I am trying to place a scene in *Friends* so I can use the episode for a school project, but I can't seem to place it. Basically, it revolves around Joey not understanding anything that the rest of the group discusses. There are a few flashbacks that occur with examples of times when Joey nods along and agrees with the conversation, but then you hear him say in his mind that he has no idea what is going on. I remember one of the examples was Ross bringing up the Constitution and Joey saying to himself that he didn't know what that was...

Does anybody know which episode this is from?

Answer (score 15):

This plot is in [The One With the Cuffs](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_The_Cuffs) (Season 4, Episode 3).

> Joey is interrupted in the middle of the day by a door-to-door encyclopedia salesman. Joey, who has never shown much interest in books, is yearning for knowledge that brings him on par with his friends' difficult subjects, so he lets the salesman in. A few basic questions asked by the salesman is all that is needed to show that Joey is not smart, which is the critical point the salesman uses to sell the encyclopedia to Joey, who starts really digging in the V volume.

Joey remembers the times he didn't get what the others were talking about:

> **Salesman:** Do your friends ever have a conversation and you just nod along even though you’re not really sure what they’re talking about?
>
> *[Flashback]*
>
> **Ross:** I’m telling you it’s totally unconstitutional.
>
> **Everyone:** Oh yeah, I totally agree. [Joey just nods]
>
> *[Another flashback]*
>
> **Monica:** I think he deserves a Nobel Prize. [Joey starts nodding]
>
> **Everyone:** No! [Joey stops nodding]
>
> *[Another flashback]*
>
> **Chandler:** It was like the Algonquin kids table. [Everyone laughs and Joey pretends to laugh too]

Comment: Remind me to never play a trivia quiz with you.  ;-)

Comment: Well, maybe not a Friends quiz... I've watched this thing way more times than I should've. :/

Comment: :-) I've seen them all, maybe 2 or 3 times… I'd still have to Google to find the 'trapped with Jill Goodacre in an ATM' scene, let alone any other. My hat goes off to you :-)